# VSCode: trigger organizeImports when git staging

Tags: javascript, git, visual-studio-code, jsx, githooks

I like the automated organize feature in VSCode, but having it doing it on every save has given me some trouble.

```
...
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.organizeImports": true
  },
...
```

Is it possible to set up some git hooks that organize the imports (either via vscode or some other script/lib) when I stage them?

### Issues

If I hit save too early (do it to kick off prettier all the time) before I have used the imported methods - then it removes it and I have to write the import again.

If I break the code (.jsx) and something appears to not be used and I hit save (to trigger prettier), then it removes the imports. I then have to import them again.

Answer (score 2):

There is some form of hook that can be applied when running `git add` : filters defined in `gitconfig` and `.gitattributes`.

See [this section of git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_keyword_expansion) for detailed explanations.

---

Here are the sketches from the documentation (it illustrates how you can configure a filter to run on `*.txt` files) :

- when running `git add` :

[image: apply the "clean" filter when adding files]

- when running `git checkout` :

[image: apply the "smudge" filter when adding files]

You can define in your `gitconfig` a filter, which consists of two commands to "clean" and "smudge" :

```
$ git config --global filter.jsximports.clean fiximports
$ git config --global filter.jsximports.smudge cat
```

and edit the `.gitattributes` file to apply this filter on jsx files

```
*.jsx    filter=jsximports
```

---

The script to apply may be `tslint --fix`, with the [`ordered-imports` rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/ordered-imports/).

Actually : `tslint`'s rule seem to have its own implementation, but it does something similar (see https://github.com/palantir/tslint/pull/4064)

In this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/57458656/86072
user thorn points to this npm package :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/organize-imports-cli
which calls organizeImports from cli

Comment: Thank you very much @LeGEC, this looks like a way to go. Do you know of a tool/script to `fiximports`?

Comment: @Norfeldt : heh :) nope. The "organizeImports" code is part of the typescript codebase, I haven't found how to call it from the command line though. You can ask a question for that part.

Comment: I do think that my question is exactly about that part ;-)

Comment: granted : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56472989/typescript-trigger-organizeimports-from-command-line

Comment: Thank you for posting that ‍♂️

Comment: It looks like someone glued the script together

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @Norfeldt : someone (thorn̈) answered the linked question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56472989