# typescript : trigger "organizeImports" from command line

Tags: javascript, typescript

VSCode has an editor feature, which allows to clean and order imports in javascript and typescript files on saving ( `"source.organizeImports": true` ).

**Question**

How can I call this action on a file from the command line ?

something like :

```
tslint --fix [apply ordered-imports rule] file1 file2
```

but it seems tslint has its own implementation for "ordered-imports"

**What I gathered so far**

From what I understood, this feature triggers a call to the `organizeImports` function in [typescript's codebase](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/services/organizeImports.ts).

This functionnality is part of typescript's Language Service, but I don't know how to start a language service daemon, and how to interact with it.

Since the code is written in that function, there also probably is a way to call it synchronously from a ts script, but I couldn't find an example of how to setup the objects and variables from scratch to feed them to this function.

Comment: I'm kind of new to VSCode, so I need to ask: What you want to do is to call the _organize imports_ feature from the _Command Palette_ on certain file? or are you talking about how to do it programatically?

Comment: I mean : being able to format a file applying the same processing from a shell script (e.g : from a git hook - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56449677 )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `organize-imports-cli` package does what you want:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/organize-imports-cli

Answer (score -2):

You can try to use [Husky](https://www.npmjs.com/package/husky) for this.

We've setup pre-commit hooks for this like so

```
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "tslint -p tsconfig.json"
    }
  }
```

You can use set such rules on all git hooks

Comment: I was looking specifically for typescript's built-in `organizeImports` action : is there a way to call this from the command line ? You can reach it through vscode "organize imports" action.